# Using xdelta: header file not found. c++

Tags: c++, diff, vcdiff

I am trying to maintain file history on a server from a client and I have thought of using xdelta for it. There is almost no help online for using xdelta. I gathered a few bits and pieces of code and tried to run it in order to understand it myself but the compiler gives the following error:

```
fatal error: xdelta3.h: No such file or directory
```

I have installed xdelta3 using apt-get as well as by downloading .tar from the [website](http://code.google.com/p/xdelta/downloads/list).

Here's the header files I included:

```
#include <xdelta3.h>
#include <xdelta3-main.h>
```

Any ideas as to what the header files for xdelta are? It will be appreciated if you could also provide some links for learning how to use xdelta since the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/xdelta/wiki/ProgrammingGuide) is insufficient for me.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, be sure that you have `-dev` package installed as well. On my Debian system I did:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libxdelta2-dev
```

Now you should be able to use those `xdelta` headers. But they can have different naming than you use. You can check it this way:

```
$ dpkg -L libxdelta2-dev | grep include
```

For me shows:

```
/usr/include/edsio_edsio.h
/usr/include/edsio.h
/usr/include/xd_edsio.h
/usr/include/xdelta.h
```

So you can see that in this case I should use `xdelta.h` header, no `xdelta3.h`. Try the same `dpkg -L` command with your `-dev` package.

If you have different version of `xdelta*-dev` package, check output of this command:

```
pkg-config --list-all | grep delta
```

For me output is empty, but if you have something like `libxdelta` in output, be sure to compile your application with these options:

```
$ gcc $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libxdelta) main.c
```

**UPDATE 1**

As for the linking issue you have. I guess you are using **gcc**, so it automatically uses correct linker for you. The thing is, you should provide library name, which you want to link your program with,  as a linker option.

First you should figure out your actual library name:

```
$ ls -1 /usr/lib | grep xdelta | grep so
```

You will see something like this:

```
libxdelta.so
libxdelta.so.2
libxdelta.so.2.0.0
```

Now you know your library name: it's part of library file name between **lib** and **.so**, in this case library name is **xdelta**.

Now you can link your program with it, using `-l` option:

```
$ gcc -lxdelta main.c
```

You may be also needed to specify path to xdelta library, if it's not a standard one (like `/usr/lib/`):

```
$ gcc -L/your/path/to/xdelta/ -lxdelta main.c
```

**UPDATE 2**

How to build and use xdelta3.

1. Obtain sources:

   ```
   cd /tmp
   wget https://xdelta.googlecode.com/files/xdelta3-3.0.8.tar.xz
   tar xJvf xdelta3-3.0.8.tar.xz 
   cd xdelta3-3.0.8/
   ```
2. Build and install:

   ```
   ./configure
   make
   sudo make install
   ```
3. Check if it works:

   ```
   cd examples/
   make clean
   make encode_decode_test
   ./encode_decode_test
   ```

If everything is fine, you should have executable file "encode_decode_test". It's example uses **xdelta3**. Now you can build your program the same way. See "Makefile" file inside of "examples" directory to get a clue how to build your program. Note that there is **no libraries** involved now.

Comment: Thanks! I installed the -dev package too. All the other outputs are same as yours. But while compiling, I get an "undefined reference to <some-function>" error. I guess this might be a linker error. What is the linker that I should use?

Comment: I have added the answer for your question above, see **UPDATE** section.

Comment: I have the given files in /usr/lib. g++ -lxdelta main.c or gcc -lxdelta main.c still does not work. The "undefined reference to..." problem still exists.

Comment: Please provide full error string and also which version of xdelta library you are using (if it's from Ubuntu repository, provide Ubuntu version and library package name).

Comment: /tmp/ccbWjchy.o: In function `main':
xd3-1.cpp:(.text+0x7e): undefined reference to `xd3_config_stream(_xd3_stream*, _xd3_config*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status.....
I am using Ubuntu 13.10; xdelta version is 1.1.3

Comment: Ok, the problem is next: you have installed library and headers for **xdelta2**, but in your code you are trying to use **xdelta3** API. So linker can't find `xd3_config_stream` function in your xdelta library, because your library basically doesn't have it. You need to install **xdelta3** library and headers first (and don't forget to remove **xdelta2** library, just in case). You should either look for xdelta3 package or build it manually.